# Give a user rights to a specific node in Drupal

Tags: drupal, types, rights

I'd like the user "student" to be assigned to a content type "Projectgroup". I can do this by adding a user reference to the Projectgroup content type form.

Example:

Projectgroup = Beta testers

Students (user referenced) = Kim, Joel, John.

When Kim logs in, she should only be able to post as "Beta testers".

How can i make sure when the user logs in he/she can only post with the correct projectgroup rights?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. You have users (Kim, Joel, John) and those users have a certain role (student). Correct? Now what is it you want to control/restrict?

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign roles to these students and then control what permissions are available to that role.

http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/user